# Display Home Page banner above the tabs

Tags: home-page-component

I created a home page component with a marquee text, but it gives only two options to position the banner. 
1. Narrow left 2. Wide right area (which is below the feeds)

I wanted to position it just above the tabs.. I was able to find an app which does this..
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005ueMvEAI

but this is not a free app..

Has anyone succeeded in displaying the banner message above the tabs in the Home page..

Comment: Do you want to see the banner above the tabs, is this a requirement? or will be ok to see the marquee as the first component above the dashboard?

Comment: Requirement is to make the banner displayed above the tabs. i made it working above the dashboard..